# How do I limit the text being pulled into my text file using XSLT?

Tags: xslt

I'm using an XSLT script to pull content from an HTML file into a .txt file. In this instance It's pulling the text in the `<li property="ktp:answer"` as well as the text in the `<section class="ktp-explanation jasper-exclude" property="ktp:explanation" typeof="ktp:Explanation">`. I only want it pull the text in the `<li>`. How can I do that?

Here's the snippet from the HTML input:

```
<li property="ktp:answer" typeof="ktp:Answer">Encourage the client to increase
                        fluid intake. <section class="ktp-explanation jasper-exclude"
                            property="ktp:explanation" typeof="ktp:Explanation">
                            <section class="ktp-explanation-section jasper-exclude"
                                data-title="Feedback" property="ktp:explanation-section"
                                typeof="ktp:feedback">
                                <p>While increasing fluid intake is important for both prevention
                                    and treatment of urinary tract infections (UTIs), it is not a
                                    priority over obtaining assessment data to confirm the suspected
                                    UTI. Fluids may be encouraged by the nurse after bacteria are
                                    determined to be present in the urine. </p>
                            </section>
                        </section>
                    </li>
```

Here's the section from my XSLT script I need to revise:

```
<xsl:when test="$colname = 'Answers'">
      <xsl:for-each select="../../../xhtml:ol[contains(@class, 'ktp-answer-set')]/xhtml:li[@property = 'ktp:answer']">
         <xsl:value-of select="concat(' (', string(position()), ') ', normalize-space(.), '|')" />
      </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:when>
```

My output is looking like this:

(1) Encourage the client to increase fluid intake. While increasing fluid intake is important for both prevention and treatment of urinary tract infections (UTIs), it is not a priority over obtaining assessment data to confirm the suspected UTI. Fluids may be encouraged by the nurse after bacteria are determined to be present in the urine.

I just need it to be this:

(1) Encourage the client to increase fluid intake.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], not snippets of code taken out of context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the `normalize-space()` in:

```xml
<xsl:value-of select="concat(' (', string(position()), ') ', normalize-space(.), '|')" />
```

to:

```xml
<xsl:value-of select="concat(' (', string(position()), ') ', normalize-space(text()[1]), '|')" />
```

so you're only normalizing the space of the first direct child node instead of the entire element that's in context.

Comment: That worked. Thanks so much, Daniel!